# Generating random numbers while using itertools product

Tags: python, random, python-itertools

I am using a generator function to create ordered lists of numbers along side itertools.product in order to create every possible paring of said numbers:

```
def gen(lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize = 1):
    for steppedVal in np.arange(lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize):
        yield steppedVal

for vectors in it.product(gen(3,6), gen(10,30,5)):
    print(vectors)
```

Which as expected produces a data set like this one:

```
(3, 10)
(3, 15)
(3, 20)
(3, 25)
(4, 10)
(4, 15)
(4, 20)
(4, 25)
(5, 10)
(5, 15)
(5, 20)
(5, 25)
```

However my problem lies in the next step. I want to add a clause to generator function to use a random number within a range instead of the stepped values. When I try the following:

```
def gen(useRandom, lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize = 1):
    if useRandom:
        randomVal = random.uniform(lowerBound, upperBound)
        yield randomVal
    else:
        for steppedVal in np.arange(lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize):
            yield steppedVal

for vectors in itertools.product(gen(True,3,6), gen(False,10,30,5)):
    print(vectors)
```

I get this, which is not what I want:

```
(4.4163620543645585, 10)
(4.4163620543645585, 15)
(4.4163620543645585, 20)
(4.4163620543645585, 25)
```

How could I modify this code so that each random number in this data set is unique without having to alter the data set after the fact as that adds huge compute overhead. (The actual data set contains a dozen or so variables with 10-20 steps each).

Edit, for clarification here is the desired output:

```
(4.1802347587349857, 10)
(3.7128578913746897, 15)
(5.8912734809721957, 20)
(4.4163620543645585, 25)
```

Edit 2, to be doubly clear I don't want to use a zip function as this should also be a possible output:

```
for vectors in itertools.product(gen(True,3,6), gen(False,10,30,5), gen(False,5,10):
    print(vectors)

(Some Random Number, 10, 5)
(Some Random Number, 10, 6)
(Some Random Number, 10, 7)
(Some Random Number, 10, 8)
(Some Random Number, 10, 9)
(Some Random Number, 15, 5)
(Some Random Number, 15, 6)
(Some Random Number, 15, 7)
(Some Random Number, 15, 8)
(Some Random Number, 15, 9)
(Some Random Number, 20, 5)
(Some Random Number, 20, 6)
(Some Random Number, 20, 7)
(Some Random Number, 20, 8)
(Some Random Number, 20, 9)
(Some Random Number, 25, 5)
(Some Random Number, 25, 6)
(Some Random Number, 25, 7)
(Some Random Number, 25, 8)
(Some Random Number, 25, 9)
```

The key part being every pairing of the 2nd and 3rd generators still exists.

Comment: I don't understand your problem? Whats the expected output ?

Comment: Do you want each of those `4.41...` values to instead be a random number between 3 and 6?

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Nathan great! would you mind making an [edit] to your question that provides some sample output that matches what you need please?

Comment: Done, thank you for all the help!

Comment: `itertools.product(gen(False,3,6), gen(False,10,30,5), gen(False,5,10))` will have 3*4*5 = 60 outputs, but it looks like you want `product(gen(True), gen(False), gen(False))` to have 4*5 = 20 outputs. I don't think you can get the effect you want just with `product`. You're going to need to use `zip` with the random generators.

Comment: That's exactly correct. However, maybe I don't understand how zip works but doesn't `zip([1,2,3],  [4,5,6])` return `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]` which is not the output I want. Or are you suggesting using zip in combination with product in order to 'append' the random numbers in a sense?

Comment: Something like  `zip(random_gen, product(range1, range2))` should give you what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: If I run exactly that I get `(random number, (lower bound of range 1, lower bound of range 2))` as my output. Is there any way to repeat the random_gen for every output of product?

Answer (score 3):

Your generator is only calling `random.uniform` once. I think you want:

```
def gen(useRandom, lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize = 1):
    for steppedVal in np.arange(lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize):
        if useRandom:
            randomVal = random.uniform(lowerBound, upperBound)
            yield randomVal
        else:
            yield steppedVal
```

Now, your output becomes:

```
(4.229914739995998, 10)
(4.229914739995998, 15)
(4.229914739995998, 20)
(4.229914739995998, 25)
(5.52362641577289, 10)
(5.52362641577289, 15)
(5.52362641577289, 20)
(5.52362641577289, 25)
(4.507985392309242, 10)
(4.507985392309242, 15)
(4.507985392309242, 20)
(4.507985392309242, 25)
```

which shows you get three different random values, corresponding to the three times the first instance of the generator runs.

Note, also, you may want to look at `random.randrange`, which essentially returns a random integer from `range(lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize)`. If you replace `random.uniform(lowerBound, upperBound)` with `random.randrange(lowerBound, upperBound, stepSize)` in the generator function, you get the output:

```
(5, 10)
(5, 15)
(5, 20)
(5, 25)
(3, 10)
(3, 15)
(3, 20)
(3, 25)
(3, 10)
(3, 15)
(3, 20)
(3, 25)
```

This time, the generator picked a random number from the set [3,4,5] on each iteration. Note that this doesn't necessarily yield unique numbers on each iteration! You can use `random.shuffle` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I use to have something similar to this, however I want each random value to be unique, I don't want to create a set of n random numbers like you have here.

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example of the desired output? It's still not quite clear to me.

Comment: @Nathan It sounds like you want something more like `zip(generator_of_random_numbers, gen(lower, upper, step))` than `product`

Comment: To my understanding zip only does direct pairings. However if I have multiple variables I still want each possible pairing, the only caveat being if paired with a random number, than number should be random